# Python- compare content of multiple text files with a master file line by line and print the difference

Tags: python

I have some issues in my program. I have been trying to come up with a script which compares text files with a master text file and the program prints out the difference.

Basically, these are network configuration and we need to compare them in bulk to make sure all devices have standard configurations. For example, the script should read each file (file1, file2..etc.)  line by line and compare it with the master file (master.txt).

I am able to compare one file at a time, however, when comparing two or more files I get an "index out of range" error.

I want to compare multiple files, probably in hundreds so I need to know how to fix his loop. Understand that this could be because program trying to ready

```
import difflib
import sys
hosts0 = open("C:\\Users\\p1329760\\Desktop\\Personal\\Python\\Projects\\sample\\master.txt","r")
hosts1 = open("C:\\Users\\p1329760\\Desktop\\Personal\\Python\\Projects\\sample\\file1.txt","r")
hosts2 = open("C:\\Users\\p1329760\\Desktop\\Personal\\Python\\Projects\\sample\\file2.txt","r")

lines1 = hosts0.readlines()
#print(lines11)

with open('output_compare.txt', 'w') as f:
    #global original_stdout 

    
    for i,lines2 in enumerate(hosts1):
        if lines2 != lines1[i]:
            original_stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = f   
            print("line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n")
            print(lines2)
            sys.stdout = original_stdout       
        else:
            pass

with open('output_compare1.txt', 'w') as file:
    
    for i,lines3 in enumerate(hosts2):
        if lines3 != lines1[i]:
             original_stdout = sys.stdout
             sys.stdout = file   
             print("line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n")
             print(lines3)
             sys.stdout = original_stdout
        else:
             pass
```

Comment: Your code is very repetitive and ideally should be using a hosts list over which you iterate to do the comparisons. Also, there are all kinds of very capable text diff programs out there.

Comment: You probably didn't get an "out of index" error. It was "list index out of range". It's important to include error messages verbatim. You also didn't tell us where the error occurred (which line of code).

Comment: The `diff3` command can do this, no programming required.

Comment: @jarmod , yes missed that the error is  "index out of range" and it happens at  if lines3 != lines1[i]: .

Comment: @TimRoberts, I trying to use this app to compare 100 files with a master file. Think diff3 only can have 3 files at a time.

Comment: You will get this error whenever one of the files to be compared has more lines then the master file. You have to catch this case explicitly or you will attempt to get a line from the master file that does not exist. You may also want to check the case in which such a file is shorter than the master, In that case your code won't catch the the files are different.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is what you could do:

You can have a list off all the file name

`namefile = [....]`

And a function which takes the file name

```
def compare (filename):
    fileobj = open(filename)
    infile = fileobj.read().split()
    for i in range(0,len(infile)):
        if infile[i] == masterin[i]:
            pass
        else:
            print(...)
```

After that you have to open the master file

```
master = open( "...")
masterin = master.read().split()
```

After that a loop and your done

```
 for i in namefile:
    compare (i)
```